# gtk themes on kde unreadable

Tags: kde, gtk, manjaro

I am running Manjaro KDE and today I discovered that my gtk themes aren't working, instead gtk applications tend to have white on white = unreadable.
How can I fix this?

I have tried setting the env variable gtk2rc.
I have tried deleting .gtkrc-2.0 file.

[example anydesk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYHdU.png)

Answer (score 0):

From [white-on-off-white](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446089/gimp-tooltips-are-almost-unreadable-white-on-off-white)

> Go to Kde system settings, then pick Application Style, then
>   pick GNOME Application Style (GTK). For both Select a GTK2
>   Theme and Select a GTK3 Theme choose HighContrast, then click
>   on Apply.

Comment: I am pretty sure this checkbox does not exist anymore